# What is the function of hadoop -jar command?

Tags: java, hadoop

I have created a java program that queries hadoop FileSystem and copies some files to local machine as such :

```
fs.copyToLocalFile(true, fiInputFile, localOutputPath, true);
```

This program does not have any mapreduce jobs.

I intend to execute it with the hadoop -jar myJar.jar command on the name node. Will this jar be executed also on the slave nodes?

Comment: It wont launch any map reduce jobs, it will run like singe java program. instead of java program you can use hadoop commands

Comment: hadoop fs -copyFromLocal source_path Destination_path(HDFS)

Comment: @KanagarajDhanapal Why won't it launch map tasks?